# Repeat one particular case statement on invalid output condition and loop inside the case

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a case statement like 1) 2) 3) ... as below where there are multiple if else condition on 1) format case.
I want to repeat the particular case on invalid condition.
When user select 1 first it ask for the name of the juice.
next it asks the availability. If yes it continues else asks for the count and does an operation. If the operation "exit 0" it just prints done. if the operation "exit 1" I wanted the loop to continue from the top ie from "name of the juice?"

```
1)
echo "Name of the Juice ?"
read juice
echo "Is it available? [Y/N]"
read deci
if [ "$deci" = "N" ]
then
echo "Continue.!"
else
echo "how many left in the warehouse ?"
read left
I have a command here which exits 0 or 1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "done"
else 
<I have to continue from the start [ie;name of the juice]>
fi
fi
;;
echo "Name of the Pizza ?"
read juice
echo "Is it available? [Y/N]"
read deci
if [ "$deci" = "N" ]
then
echo "Continue.!"
else
echo "how many left ?"
read left
I have a command here which exits 0 or 1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "done"
else 
<I have to continue from the start [ie;name of the juice]>
fi
fi
;;
```

Comment: Put it all in a continual loop (e.g. `while :; do ..#your code; done`) then just add `continue` where you need to go to the start. (or just let it loop if you have no statements you need to skip by executing the `continue`)

Comment: You may want to start indenting your code, it would make it far easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to read, but if I understand correctly, you want to loop within one of your cases and make decisions on whether to continue back to the start of that case statement, or whether to leave. That can be done by putting the contents of that particular case in an infinite loop with `while :` and then using `continue` to return to the beginning of the loop at any point, or using `break` to break out of the loop at any point.

Not passing on the remainder of your code, but you could handle case `1)` of your case statement similar to:

```
1)
    while :
    do
        printf "Name of the Juice?: "
        read -r juice
        printf "Is it available? [Y/N]: "
        read -r deci
        if [ "$deci" = "N" ] || [ "$deci" = "n" ]
        then
            printf "Continue.!\n"
        else
            printf "how many left in the warehouse?: "
            read -r left
            # I have a command here which exits 0 or 1
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                printf "done\n"
                break   ## break out of loop
            else 
                continue
            fi
        fi

        printf "Name of the Pizza?: "
        read -r juice   ## why juice - I thought this was pizza?
        printf "Is it available? [Y/N]: "
        read -r deci
        if [ "$deci" = "N" ] || [ "$deci" = "n" ]
        then
            printf "Continue.!\n"
        else
            printf "how many left?: "
            read -r left
            # I have a command here which exits 0 or 1
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                printf "done"
                break   ## break out of loop
            else 
                continue
            fi
        fi
    done
    ;;  # your case termination from where?
```

Please add further explanation of any additional requirements you have and post the complete script you are working on as [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I am happy to help further.